# Where is the best place to ask a question about how to set software on a new (Mac) computer?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, github, osx

My present home computer is a bit of a disorganized mess with a semblance of organization. More than anything, this reflects the fact that I learned to code over the time that I owned this computer, more or less.

Thus, I would have new ideas on how to do things, or forget that I had things, etc. etc. I also was experimenting with installers, learning what Git and Docker were, etc.

This time around, I want to start off in a logical, organized way to build something that will remain orderly over time. To start this process, one thing I want to do is (on day one), to download a laundry list of everything I need. Examples include,

- [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager))
- Python 3.8 [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution))
- [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)
- Docker Desktop
- upgraded package managers like [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29)
- help [.bashrc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)/[.bash_profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Legacy-compatible_Bash_startup_example)
- [RStudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RStudio)
- cloud storage options/AWS

I think this kind of post is likely to get downvoted, because it is sort of asking about preferences and prior experiences. Nevertheless, there is a great deal of relevant knowledge and life experience out there. I am betting that there are people who have thought a lot about this, and that, on day one, they already know exactly what they will do and how they will do it...

---

At last, here's my question:  Where can I read about the way experienced programmers set up their stuff when they get a new computer? Everything from installers themselves, to folder structure for their own code, to aliasing, to ... I’m not sure what else. I think if I could read blog entries, examples, etc. It would give me ideas id want.

The hardest part seems to be to be linking everything together intelligently ... I have [Obsidian](https://www.marclittlemore.com/beginners-guide-note-taking-obsidian/) for notes, and Git for code, and Docker for ... also sort of code, and my own Python classes ... just not sure how to integrate it all well.

Where do you think such a post as this belongs?

Comment: Re *"read about the way experienced programmers set up their stuff when they get a new computer"*: A good bet [would be](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2022/06/29/setting-up-firefox-on-a-new-system/) [blog posts](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2020/03/29/using-geany/).

Comment: There must be plenty of YouTube and [Odysee](https://odysee.com/) channels as well. A starting point is [Ali Abdaal](https://www.youtube.com/c/aliabdaal/videos) (general productivity) and [Jeff Geerling](https://www.youtube.com/c/JeffGeerling/videos) (sample: *[Automating setting up a new (Mac) computer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VhPVu5EK5o)*).

Comment: I can see a point in asking the meta question, but including part of the shopping list seems to be just begging to get partial answers to the real question. You might want to remove those parts.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for https://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Probably Hashnode is a good place to find such very personal opinions.

Answer (score 17):

Doesn't belong anywhere on the network.

You're asking about what it is you need to download to get set up to program. Problem is that this isn't a precise science, and probably never will be a precise science.

A lot of these things you probably know to install up front, and a lot of these things you'll probably want to install as you go along.

If you were having trouble with getting them installed - for instance, there was something funky going on with Homebrew - then *maybe* Ask Different would be suitable.

As it is, you're looking for a laundry list of stuff to install.  That's just too open of a question.

Comment: A specific, focused question on how to set up a _particular_ programming environment _could_ be on-topic (e.g., what are the _minimum_ things to install to get X language set up in Y IDE).  However, I concur with you that this example of a laundry list of software for multiple technologies (I note at least R and Python, plus Docker, as well as general setup tips for dotfiles) is not on-topic anywhere on the network.

Comment: Yep, I touch on this with my Homebrew example @RyanM.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with your answer as written. I just wanted to add that a _slightly_ broader example than that (but still _far_ less broad than the example in this question) could also be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange sites, including but limited to Stack Overflow, are **not discussion fora**.

There is https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com, but the same requirement for a *specific, focused* question applies. "Which program should I go with for X task" qualifies; "what programs do I need in order to Do Programming" does not, because that entails first [figuring out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) *what the X tasks are*, and then separately asking about each (of course, first attempting to find answers for yourself, and checking for existing duplicates of those questions).

For "putting together a laundry list", ask your friends, or **think** and start writing stuff down. Maybe check some blogs for inspiration. The fact that you've *heard of* Git means you already have a leg up. For guidance and tutoring, look for guides and tutorials. Search engines [work better than you might think](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=what+software+do+I+need+to+program+in+python+on+a+mac). For discussion, look for a discussion forum (for example, somewhere on Reddit).